# Is Recon-ng still relevant?

Tags: recon-ng

I noticed that `Recon-ng` is part of [PWK/OSCP syllabus](https://www.offensive-security.com/documentation/penetration-testing-with-kali.pdf).

I decided to give it a try. However, the module `google_site_web` doesn't seems to work anymore.

```
[recon-ng][default] > modules load recon/domains-hosts/google_site_web
[recon-ng][default][google_site_web] > options set SOURCE vulnweb.com
SOURCE => vulnweb.com
[recon-ng][default][google_site_web] > run

-----------
VULNWEB.COM
-----------
[*] Searching Google for: site:vulnweb.com
[!] Google CAPTCHA triggered. No bypass available.
[recon-ng][default][google_site_web] >
```

Is there any solution for this?

Also, I noticed that [the last update](https://github.com/lanmaster53/recon-ng) for `Recon-ng` was on Jun 24, 2020. Is this tool still relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure how an update time of 6 months ago means that it is not relevant nor the fact that the module works but didn't work as expected on that one site means that "it doesn't work anymore".

Answer (score 4):

Relevant? Absolutely. Most tools don't just go out of relevancy (unless they're replaced/upgraded). They all have a place in a wider methodology hence why it is in the PWK materials.